# MongoEngine ValidationError

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

i have to creating a database and what to check whether all the entries are being input in the database or not using the python shell.

i wrote a class called Trial

```
class Trial(db.Document):
    project_name = db.StringField(max_length=255,required=True)
    list_of_materials = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('List_Of_Materials'))
    abstract = db.StringField(max_length=255,required=True)
    vehicle = db.StringField(max_length=255,required=False)
    responsibilities = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Responsibilities'))
```

and i defined classes List_of_Materials and Responsibilities as follows:

```
class Responsibilities(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    employee = db.StringField(max_length=255, required = True)
    objective = db.StringField(max_length=255, required = True)

class List_Of_Materials(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    mat_name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    mat_type = db.StringField()
    mat_comments = db.StringField(max_length = 255)
```

now i use the python shell to make an entry into the database.

```
trial_test = Trial(project_name = 'nio field trip management',
                list_of_materials = [List_Of_Materials(mat_name = 'Laptop')],
                abstract = 'All is well that ends well',
                vehicle = Vehicle(veh_name='My Laptop',veh_num='GA07EX1234'),
                responsibilities = [Responsibilities(employee='Prashant',objective='Setup the Website')],
```

and i get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\document.py", line 85, in __init__
    value = field.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\fields.py", line 261, in to_python
    self.error('You can only reference documents once they'
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mongoengine\base\fields.py", line 124, in error
raise ValidationError(message, errors=errors, field_name=field_name)
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: You can only reference documents once they have been saved to the database
```

LINE 12 of the code is `responsibilities=db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Responsibilities'))`

What i could interpret from the above error is that we can have to first entry into the classes "Responsibilities" and "List_Of_Material" , but the entry in "List_Of_Material" does not show any error while the ones in "Responsibilities" show the above error.

What can i do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the `Trial` model you send is the right one ?

This ValidationError is thrown when you declare a ReferenceField in a document, but you try to save this document before saving the referenced document (Mongoengine represents a reference field in MongoDB as an dictionary containing the class and the ObjectId of the reference).

`EmbeddedDocumentField` is not `ReferenceField`. They are saved at the same time as you save the main document. Thus, I don't think your error is coming from either `list_of_materials` or `responsibilities` attribute. If you remove the vehicle assignment in your example, this code works perfectly.

Given your code example, I am guessing there is a class like

```
class Vehicle(db.Document):
    veh_name = db.StringField()
    veh_num = db.StringField()
```

and your model is:

```
class Trial(db.Document):
    project_name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    list_of_materials = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('List_Of_Materials'))
    abstract = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    vehicle = db.ReferenceField(Vehicle)
    responsibilities = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Responsibilities'))
```

And then, your example should be:

```
trial_test = Trial(
     project_name = 'nio field trip management',
     list_of_materials = [List_Of_Materials(mat_name = 'Laptop')],
     abstract = 'All is well that ends well',
     vehicle = Vehicle(veh_name='My Laptop',veh_num='GA07EX1234'),
     responsibilities = [Responsibilities(employee='Prashant',objective='Setup the Website')]
)
trial_test.vehicle.save()  # Saving the reference BEFORE saving the trial.
trial_test.save()
```